# Modifying Form Elements in CKEditor

Tags: javascript, html, forms, ckeditor

I apologize in advance for the generality of the question.  There is a surprising lack of documentation or discussion about this.  If someone can point me to some source on this topic it would be much appreciated.

I'm trying to create a CMS page where users can edit custom forms.  I'm using CKEditor in a pretty simple HTML/JavaScript setup like the demo on their website http://ckeditor.com/demo#full

My problem is this - Form elements can be resized (and drag-and-dropped) in IE but not in Chrome or FireFox.

If anyone has any information on editing form elements in CKEditor please let me know about it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's not related to CKEditor but to `contenteditable` in general, which, quite frankly, is not consistent in terms of implementation because it lacks standarisation. There's nothing you can do about it unless you implement that feature from scratch, which is not a good idea really, especially because I'm not quite sure that default behavior can be disabled.

Comment: In general, in Chrome contenteditable="true" has the desired effect.  However, CKEditor is setting that on the content div and it is not working.

Comment: Further testing reveals that contenteditable IS working in Chrome, it just isn't doing what I want it to.

Answer (score 0):

The form elements resizing feature may be supported by the browser (e.g. IE) not by javascript code. So it's hard to make the feature available in Chrome or FireFox.